# How to refactor Handlebars template and helper code in Meteor when pass parameters?

Tags: javascript, meteor, handlebars.js

Any idea how to allow my BioPic Handlebars helper (I'm using Meteor) to allow different contexts for the param 'owner'. I'm calling showBioPic as a partial from another template i.e.

```
<template name="myMain">
    {{#each post}}
        {{> showBioPic}}
    {{/each}}
    Do a bunch of other stuff here too.
</template>
```

I want be able to pass in different 'owner' values depending on the calling template, i.e. Meteor.userId, post.owner, anotherUsersId. i.e. if I used {{#each user}} this doesn't have an owner field, it has a userId, so BioPic helper would not work.

```
<template name="showBioPic">        
    {{#with BioPic owner}}
        <img src="{{cfsFileUrl 'size48x48gm'}}" alt="Profile Picture: {{_id}}">
    {{else}}
        <img class="showShared" src="images/default-biopic-48x48.png" alt="Default Profile Picture">
    {{/with}}
</template>


Template.showBioPic.BioPic = function (IN_ownerId)    
   return BioPicsFS.findOne( { owner: IN_ownerId });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

If using a Template helper is an option, then something like this should work:

```
Template.myMain.helpers({
  showBioPicWithContext: function (owner) {
    return Template.showBioPic(owner);
  }
});

<template name="myMain">
    {{#each post}}
        {{showBioPicWithContext id}}
    {{/each}}
    Do a bunch of other stuff here too.
</template>

<template name="showBioPic">
    {{#if _id}}
        <img src="{{cfsFileUrl 'size48x48gm'}}" alt="Profile Picture: {{_id}}">
    {{else}}
        <img class="showShared" src="images/default-biopic-48x48.png" alt="Default Profile Picture">
    {{/if}}
</template>
```

Comment: Pretty sure this won't work since {{cfsFileUrl}} requires a #each or #with to work, it's a helper from CollectionFS. Also if the _id I need is in a field called owner, your code would not work as per {{#if _id}} would need to be {{#with owner}}, which would break the case where I do need to check for _id as in {{#with _id}}.

Comment: is cfsFileUrl not a field within owner (the data object passed to the template in js)?

Comment: No, cfsFileUrl is a Handlebars helper, from CollectionFS, see here: https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-CollectionFS

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain if I understand the details of your problem, but in one of my projects I do something like this:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('BioPic', function(user) {
  if (_.isString(user)) {
    // assume user is an id
  } else {
    // assume user is an object like Meteor.user()
  }
});
```

Handlebars helpers are just functions, so you you can test the value of the parameter passed to them and act accordingly. In the above example, when `user` is a string we could assume it's an id and return something like `Pictures.findOne({owner: user});`. You can just add more clauses based on all possible variations of the `user` input.

Comment: Thanks, although it's getting a bit Pearl like with a function that behaves differently depending on the parameter passed in. I'd like to avoid that kind of ambiguity. I may still try this if I can't figure anything else out.

Comment: I keep all of my helpers in a single file, and the is-id-or-object test is a common idiom between them so it doesn't look bad. I agree if this had more than 2 clauses, it would be pretty hard to maintain. If you think of something better let me know.